# Why does this SPARQL query not return any data if using OFFSET greater than 0

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I am trying to retrieve music information from DBPedia. If I run this query on http://dbpedia.org/sparql/:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
?title 
?date 
(group_concat(distinct ?label;separator=";;;") as ?labels)
(group_concat(distinct ?genre;separator=";;;") as ?genres)
(group_concat(distinct ?member;separator=";;;") as ?members)
(group_concat(distinct ?oldMember;separator=";;;") as ?oldMembers)
(group_concat(distinct ?origin;separator=";;;") as ?origins)
(group_concat(distinct ?song;separator=";;;") as ?songs)
(group_concat(distinct ?songOther;separator=";;;") as ?songOthers)
(group_concat(distinct ?songOtherOther;separator=";;;") as ?songOtherOthers)
WHERE {
   ?title <http://purl.org/dc/terms/subject>      <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:American_hard_rock_musical_groups> .
   OPTIONAL { ?title <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/bandMember> ?member . }
   OPTIONAL { ?title <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/formerBandMember> ?oldMember . }
   OPTIONAL { ?title <http://dbpedia.org/property/label> ?label . }
   OPTIONAL { ?title <http://dbpedia.org/property/genre> ?genre . }
   OPTIONAL { ?title <http://dbpedia.org/property/origin> ?origin . } 
   OPTIONAL { ?title <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/activeYearsStartYear> ?date . }
   OPTIONAL { ?song <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/artist> ?title . }
   OPTIONAL { ?songOther <http://dbpedia.org/property/artist> ?title . }
   OPTIONAL { ?songOtherOther <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/musicalArtist> ?title . }
} ORDER BY ?title ?date LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0
```

I get one result, yet if I change `OFFSET` to `1` the result set is empty? (for sure there is more than one result available)

Any ideas?

Comment: The problem is in `property/artist` and `ontology/musicalArtist` predicates, without them it works fine. I don't know, but to me it looks like a Virtuoso bug.

Comment: Thanks @laughedelic, yes I understand, but without those I don't get songs information which are important for my project. I could do it programmatically, like get first each band and for each band then get the songs, just wanted to know if there was a more compact way.

Comment: Do you need `song`, `songOther` and `songOtherOther` separately?

Comment: @laughedelic, nope, they can be all together in one binding.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution I found was to split the query in multiple queries using Python:

1. Create a JSON to specify/define what is needed:

   ```
   [{
   "root": [
       "?title <http://purl.org/dc/terms/subject> <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:American_hard_rock_musical_groups> .",
       "?title <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/isPrimaryTopicOf> ?name "
   ],
   "sub_page": [
      "?title <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/isPrimaryTopicOf> <[[X]]> .",
      "OPTIONAL { ?title <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/bandMember> ?member . }",
      "OPTIONAL { ?title <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/formerBandMember> ?oldMember . }",
      "OPTIONAL { ?title <http://dbpedia.org/property/label> ?label . }",
      "OPTIONAL { ?title <http://dbpedia.org/property/genre> ?genre . }",
      "OPTIONAL { ?title <http://dbpedia.org/property/origin> ?origin . }", 
      "OPTIONAL { ?title <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/activeYearsStartYear> ?date . }", 
      "OPTIONAL { ?song <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/artist> ?title . }",
      "OPTIONAL { ?songOther <http://dbpedia.org/property/artist> ?title . }", 
      "OPTIONAL { ?songOtherOther <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/musicalArtist> ?title . }",
      "OPTIONAL { ?songOtherOtherOther <http://dbpedia.org/property/producer> ?title}"

   ],
   "service":"<http://dbpedia.org/sparql/>",
   "select":[
               "title",
               "date",
               "label_s",
               "genre_s",
               "member_s",
               "oldMember_s",
               "origin_s",
               "song_s",
               "songOther_s",
               "songOtherOther_s",
               "songOtherOtherOther_s",
               "name_X"
       ], 
   "language": "en", 
   "limit": 10000,
   "offset": 100,
   "category": "music",
   "description": "American Hard Rock",
   "sub_category": "American_hard_rock_musical_groups"
   }]
   ```
2. Then use this Python script to consume the JSON:

   ```
   import os, sys
   from api.DBPedia import DBPedia
   import datetime 
   import time
   import copy
   import json
   class ProcessStuff(DBPedia):
       def __init__(self, fn = "" ):
           """Initialize ProcessStuff class"""
           self.filePath = fn

       def getConfigFile(self):
           """Reads json file with dbpedia query information"""
           try:
               jsonFile = open(self.filePath, "r")
               data = json.load(jsonFile)
               jsonFile.close()
               return data
           except Exception as e:
               print "[getConfigFile] Error in reading file: %s" % e

       def queryMultiplier(self, data, identifier = '[[X]]'):
           """Generate new DBPedia queries based on previous query result."""
           queries = []
           q = self.createSparqlQuery(data)
           json_page = self.resolveDBPediaQuery(q = q)
           if len(data['sub_page']) > 0:
               try:
                   items = json_page['results']['bindings']
                   for item in items:
                       sub_data = copy.deepcopy(data)
                       # Only allows for one identifier
                       sub_page_identifier = [var for var in data['select'] if var.endswith('_X')][0].replace('_X','')
                       name = item[sub_page_identifier]['value']
                       count = 0
                       while count < len(sub_data['sub_page']):
                           if identifier in sub_data['sub_page'][count]:
                               sub_data['sub_page'][count] = sub_data['sub_page'][count].replace(identifier,name)
                           count += 1
                       q = self.createSparqlQuery(sub_data, key = 'sub_page')
                       queries.append(q)
               except Exception as e:
                   print "[ProcessStuff][queryMultiplier] Error in creating queries for subpages: %s" % e
                   pass
               for query in queries:
                   file_name = data['category']+"___"+data['sub_category']
                   print "Fetching query: \n%s" % query
                   json_page = self.resolveDBPediaQuery(q = query)
                   print "Processin page and saving to: "+ file_name
                   self.processPage(json_page, json_file = '../../json_samples/', category = file_name, overwrite = False)

       def createConcat(self, data, separator = ";;;"):
           """ Creates concat string. """
           return "(group_concat(distinct ?"+data+";separator='"+separator+"') as ?"+data+"_s)" 

       def createSparqlQuery(self, data, separator = ";;;", key = "root", offset = 100):
           """Generates SPARQL query from input file."""
           query = []
           orderby = []
           select = "SELECT DISTINCT"
           #from_each_subpage
           for prop in data['select']:
               if prop.endswith("_s"):
                   select +=" "+ self.createConcat(prop.split("_s")[0])
               else:
                   v = "?"+ prop.replace('_X','')
                   select += " "+ v
                   orderby.append(v)
           where = " WHERE { "
           closing = 1
           query.append(select)
           query.append(where)
           try:
               service = "SERVICE "+data['service'] + " {"
               query.append(service)
               closing += 1
           except:
               pass
           query.append('\n'.join(data[key]))
           while closing > 0:
               query.append('}')
               closing -= 1
           o = " ORDER BY " + ' '.join(orderby)
           query.append(o)
           try:
               limit = data['limit']
               l = " LIMIT %s" % limit
               query.append(l)
           except:
               pass

           complete_query = '\n'.join(query)
           print complete_query
           return complete_query

   if __name__ == "__main__":
       try:
           JSON_FILE_NAME = sys.argv[1]
       except:
           print "JSON file name is needed to run!"
           sys.exit(2)
       start_time = datetime.datetime.now().time().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
       hm = ProcessStuff(JSON_FILE_NAME)
       data = hm.getConfigFile()
       hm.queryMultiplier(data[0])
       end_time = datetime.datetime.now().time().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
       total_time=(datetime.datetime.strptime(end_time,'%H:%M:%S') - datetime.datetime.strptime(start_time,'%H:%M:%S'))
       print "Took %s to process %s " % (total_time, JSON_FILE_NAME)
   ```
3. Then run the code as follows `python ProcessStuff.py input.json`
4. Took 0:31:10 to process music.json, 441 entries processed

For sure the code could be made faster...
The DBPedia class which ProcessStuff inherits from is simply to make the HTTP request, clean up the results a bit and save the results as JSON.

Comment: It's great that you solved your problem. But I think this doesn't answer your original question (why that the query doesn't work as expected) and is not a SPARQL solution to it.

Comment: @laughedelic fair enough :)

Answer (score -1):

`group_concat` is an aggregator.

The entire result are grouped and turned into a single group with one result row.  Hence `OFFSET 0` returns one row, `OFFSET 1` returns no rows.

Did you mean to use

```
GROUP BY ?title
```

?

Example:

```
SELECT (count(*) AS ?C)
WHERE 
{ ?s ?p ?o }
```

One row, the count.

Comment: could you clarify the hence...? Why other queries return more results? Also, if I remove the limit clause I get `Virtuoso 22026 Error SR319: Max row length is exceeded when trying to store a string of 3145 chars into a temp col`

Comment: I think that Virtuoso here allows to omit explicit grouping. I also tried adding it explicitly, but it didn't change anything.